# Adobe Air File.open generates error #3003 on Android

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

I'm doing something really simple - so there must be silly mistake somewhere here. I'm building my game with:

```
adt -package -target apk-debug -connect  -storetype pkcs12 -keystore "cert\mygame.p12" -storepass fd "dist\mygame-debug.apk" "application.xml" -C bin . -C "icons/android" .
```

With the swfs and required data files in the bin/ folder. That -C directive should make them work as root, as per Adobe docs. Then in code all I'm doing is:

```
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("data.json");
var fin:FileStream = new FileStream();
fin.open(file, FileMode.READ);     // error 3003 triggered!!
```

The path is resolved to "app:/data.json" which is correct, since it lives in the apk in the same place the swf is.

So why am I getting error 3003? Any insight is greatly appreciated!

I'm building with Air 3.7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have this permission enabled in your `app.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`File.applicationDrectory` represents the folder your app is installed to on the device. In Android this directory is heavily protected, you need root access to read from there (which I'm assuming you don't have). `File.applicationStorageDirectory` is a more preferable place to read/write from, this is within your applications "sandbox" (no other apps, or the user, can access it without root access, but your app can).

Answer (score 0):

firstly update your air to 13 from labs.adobe.com
if updated air sdk will not solve issue - try to use URLLoader instead FileStream